# How to create an "inline" object to contain members for a ComboBox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have an enumeration in the form:

```
Public Enum MyCollections As Integer
    My_Stuff = 0
    My_Things = 1
End Enum
```

I would like to use these as values in a ComboBox, but I would like to display the strings "My Stuff" and "My Things" respectively.

I'm sure I've seen a method for quickly creating some kind of local object definition where I can assign a string property to be displayed, and a "MyCollections" type property to store the value of the enum element, but I can't for the life of me think of how to explain that to a search engine.

Can anyone interpet my vague memories into some code I can use to set a DataSource for my ComboBox and retrieve the data when a user changes the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it looks as though I was thinking of "anonymous types". Here's some code that answer the (vary, very vague) question I as trying to ask:

```
Private Sub TestCodeForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim addOutcomes As New Collection
    For Each enumIn As MyCollections In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(MyCollections))
        addOutcomes.Add(New With {.Display = [Enum].GetName(GetType(MyCollections), enumIn), .Value = enumIn})
    Next

    Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display"
    Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
    Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = addOutcomes
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    MsgBox("Display: " & CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem.Display & vbCrLf &
           "Value: " & CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem.value.GetType.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I like creating a simple object and filling the ComboBox with a collection of my simple object. Then I set the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property of the ComboBox to the name of the property I want displayed from my simple object.

```
'Something like this
Class SimpleObject
    Property Name As String
End Class

'And then later...
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that, but I've got a mental itch now, regarding the specific subject of my question, and I'm hoping someone will come along and scratch it. I might eventually choose to do things the way you suggest, I'm just trying to fill a blank page in my memory book, if you see what I mean... I really think I should have gotten more sleep last night...

Comment: OK, cool. Sorry i cant remember what you did ;) i find myself trying to pin down old solutions too, they're hard to remember!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want - it enumerates the enumeration, listing the value and the text string of the value (taking out the underscores):

```
    Dim enumValue As Integer, enumName As String
    For Each enumValue In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(MyCollections))
        enumName = System.Enum.GetName(GetType(MyCollections), enumValue).Replace("_", " ")
        Debug.WriteLine(enumValue.ToString + ";" + enumName)
    Next
```

*Output:*

```
0;My Stuff
1;My Things
```

Putting this data into a combobox will require a databind which will [probably require a custom class](http://blog.verkoyen.eu/blog/p/detail/vb-net-add-items-with-value-and-display-into-comboboxes) in your case but the code above may get you started.